# Reviews weighing system that takes into account users's preferences

Tags: javascript, node.js

In terms of open source implementations of ratings aggregation I've only seen derivatives of this: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

I'm looking for a system that takes into account user preferences on top of the Wilson score confidence interval.

For example if a user with 10 ratings on only action movies rates a romance movie negatively "too boring", the algorithm would weigh that rating lower than someone with 10 ratings on romance movies.

Can anyone explain how to do this properly or link to an existing implementation of it. Thanks.